# Trouble with permissions and Samba on Ubuntu Server

Tags: 14.04, permissions, samba

I thought I understood permissions well, but apparently there is something I still don't understand.

I have a samba share running on my Ubuntu 14.04.1 server.

The intention is to use this for my family at home to use. I created a user called myfamily in a group called family. I put the usernames of the people in my family including myself in the group family.

The directory, share, has these permissions for the sake of troubleshooting: drwxrwxrwx

I would prefer drwxrwxr-x

It is owned by the myfamily username and is in the family group.

I can connect with my computer (OSX) to the samba server with my username and with the myfamily username.

All directories and files within the share folder have the following permissions:
drwxrwxr-x

If I try to write a file to a directory owned by myfamily in the share while logged in as my username, I don't have permission to write but can read.
The same results for if I am logged in to the share as myfamily and I try to write to a folder owned by me.

The way I understood it is if a user is a part of a group and permissions are set 775, then users of that group can write to folders in that group regardless of the owner.

My the part of my /etc/samba/smb.conf file for this:

```
[share]
    comment = Family share on server
    create mode = 775
    writable = yes
    directory mode = 775
    public = yes               
    path = /media/raid1/share
```

Thanks for any help.

Jason